# Round Julia's Millisecond type to nearest Second or Minute

Tags: julia

I would like to calculate the difference between a pair of DateTimes that is rounded to the nearest second or minute.

```
initial = now()
println(typeof(initial))
sleep(12)
final = now()
difference = final - initial
println(typeof(difference))
```

gives

```
DateTime
Base.Dates.Millisecond
```

The latter type is pretty difficult to use since almost all convenience types are for `DateTime`s. What is the recommend way to convert `difference` to seconds or fractional minutes? Is this possible without dropping down to integers? I would prefer to avoid that since it is more error prone.

Comment: Would you want to convert from milliseconds to integer, like: `convert(Int64, difference)`? Or to a `DateTime`?

Comment: That was a typo in my question. I would prefer to avoid integers, if possible.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you are looking for `Dates.epochms2datetime(difference)`. [Dates.epochms2datetime](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/dates/?highlight=datetime#Dates.epochms2datetime) will convert milliseconds to a `DateTime` type (for the example at the question, it will give approximately `0000-01-01T00:00:21.608`), so you can convert the result with [Accessor Functions](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/dates/?highlight=datetime#accessor-functions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `difference` represents a duration between dates rather than a particular time, it makes sense for it to just be a duration in milliseconds. Additionally, `DateTime` and `Base.Dates.Millisecond` objects are internally represented with an `Int64`, so everything's already an integer.

```
julia> moment = now()
2016-12-22T22:54:57.393

julia> dump(moment)
DateTime
  instant: Base.Dates.UTInstant{Base.Dates.Millisecond}
    periods: Base.Dates.Millisecond
      value: Int64 63618130497393

julia> dump(now()-moment)
Base.Dates.Millisecond
  value: Int64 29820
```

Divide the value in milliseconds by 1000 to get seconds, or by 60,000 to get minutes. Use `round()` to round to the nearest second or minute.

```
julia> d = (now() - moment).value/60_000
3.9330833333333333

julia> e = round(d)
4.0
```

Then multiply by 1000 or 60,000 and feed it back into `Dates.Millisecond` to turn the rounded figure back into the appropriate object:

```
julia> Dates.Millisecond(60_000e)
240000 milliseconds
```

Rounding a `Date` or `DateTime` object to a given time interval is much simpler, as you can just use `round()` according to the [documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/dates/#rounding) and it will dispatch to a relevant method:

> ```
> julia> floor(Date(1985, 8, 16), Dates.Month)
> 1985-08-01
>
> julia> ceil(DateTime(2013, 2, 13, 0, 31, 20), Dates.Minute(15))
> 2013-02-13T00:45:00
>
> julia> round(DateTime(2016, 8, 6, 20, 15), Dates.Day)
> 2016-08-07T00:00:00
> ```